# Google Chrome changes focus when typing

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I've been experiencing odd behavior when using Google Chrome on Windows lately

I use two languages when I'm typing, English and Arabic

when I press shift+Alt to switch to Arabic ,the textbox loses its focus and I have to click on the textbox again to continue writing

is this a bug,or an unknown feature of Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue 45091: Keyboard language shift is broken with chrome + flash objects](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45091) says:

> it only happen at first time when user
>   hold Shift key first then press Alt
>   key once. if I hold on Alt and press
>   Shift key, or try to press both keys
>   at same time, this issue does not
>   occur.
>
> I have finally reproduced this issue
>   today and investigated it. In brief,
>   this issue is caused by our WindowWin
>   class that consumes the first
>   Shift+Alt key event (which raises a
>   WM_SYSCOMMAND message) to set the menu
>   focus to the wrench icon and does not
>   dispatch it to the plugin.

I don't know if this known problem is the one you are encountering, but you might try pressing Alt before also pressing Shift.

Comment: this issue isn't exactly what I'm talking about,but pressing ALT really works!,thanks a lot